# Safely have many users execute stored proc in Sql Server concurrently

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have built a worklist using SSRS and multiple users will utilize the report concurrently. I have multiple UPDATE/INSERT statements in the stored proc that uses parameters to execute accordingly. It's a fast query, but my concern is, what if 2 users tried the same action on different records, at the same time. I have read a lot about locking and table hints, and have not had much luck finding a solid answer. I don't want to lock users, but more or less queue up transactions accordingly.

```
IF @ID = 0 
BEGIN

UPDATE TABLEA SET MYVALUE = 1 , USER = @USERID, RECDATE = GETDATE();

END

IF @ID = 1
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TABLE B 
SELECT @ACCOUNTID , @SOMEVALUE , @USERID, GETDATE();

END
```

So this code is a simplified version on what's happening. What's the best process of making it so that if the proc is executing, and the second user kicks it off, it'll queue their execution until the first one is complete? This is in SSMS 2012. Thank you.

Comment: SQL handles this automatically for you... However your UPDATE statement does not have a where clause, so it will currently update all the records in the table, is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Milney. No, my real code does, I just wanted to add a simplistic piece of code for example purposes. I am only updating one row at a time on certain actions.

Comment: What exactly you want to queue - entire SP or update/insert statement?

Comment: if user 1 executes the same action as user 2 concurrently, queue just that specific update/insert respectively.

Comment: As said, the database already does that. Statements are atomic and isolated -- if two statements execute at the same time, the database will ensure the results are identical to what would happen if you executed them separately (though the order in which they happen is not defined; if you need a defined order, you must synchronize externally). If necessary, locks will be taken to ensure this, which is transparent to you (unless a deadlock occurs). These locks are as granular as possible to minimize contention, typically row by row, so statements operating on different rows don't interfere.

Comment: Great, that certainly provides comfort. I just wanted to ensure data integrity. Thank you all!